# Help with auto-deployment script with Hudson

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous-deployment

We are developing a auto-deployment script that needs to run in Hudson's "Execute Shell" step.Currently the script reads param
1. GroupId:ArctifactId:Version:Packaging(The project is Mavenized)
2. Servername:VahRoot:TcInstance

I need to read G:A:V:P param from pom.xml which is specified in the Hudson Job configuration. Although Hudson provide WORKSPACE env-var it becomes difficult to search for pom.xml in the workspace , considering there might be scenario where the current executing pom name is pom.xyz.xml.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage()
{
echo "Usage: $0 -s-r-g-a-v-p-i";
exit 1;
}

if [ $# -lt 14 ] ; then
usage;
fi

# ":" decides which options require an argument
while getopts s:r:g:a:v:p:i: opt
do
case "$opt" in
s) echo "hello $OPTARG";
serverName=$OPTARG;;
r) echo "hello $OPTARG";
vahroot=$OPTARG;;
g) echo "hello $OPTARG";
groupid=$OPTARG;;
a) echo "hello $OPTARG";
artifactid=$OPTARG;;
v) echo "hello $OPTARG";
version=$OPTARG;;
p)echo "hello $OPTARG";
packagetype=$OPTARG;;
i)echo "hello $OPTARG";
tcinstance=$OPTARG;;
\?) usage;;
esac
done
cd $vahroot
echo "Now in $vahroot"
source $vahroot/admin/env/vahenv.sh
tcmgr.sh restart -t all
echo "$?"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo "Exception occured"
exit 1;
fi
version_chk="SNAPSHOT"
if [[ $version =~ $version_chk ]]
then
echo "groupid is $groupid artifactid $artifactid version $version packagetype             $packagetype tcinstance $tcinstance"
tcmgr.sh deploy -w nexus://snapshots:$groupid:$artifactid:$version:$packagetype -i     $tcinstance
exit 0;
else
echo "groupid is $groupid artifactid $artifactid version $version packagetype     $packagetype tcinstance $tcinstance"
tcmgr.sh deploy -w nexus://releases:$groupid:$artifactid:$version:$packagetype -i     $tcinstance
exit 0;
fi
```

I need help with read the hudson config to give me the pom location specified in the job so that I need not ask the user to enter the G:A:V:P param.

Comment: Why not writing a java programm which reads the POm and the information needed  or write a Maven Plugin to do the work or write a Hudson Plugin to do that...

Answer (score 0):

There are several deployment plugins available for hudson (jenkins) that can do the job for you. In case this is not an option for you: you can pass the hudson environment variable `WORKSPACE` to your script and relative to that it should be easy to find the pom.xml in the workspace.

Comment: Well yes I can do that.But the workspace may contain multiple pom as mentioned pom.xyz.xml , pom.abc.xml etc . I need to get to the pom used by the current hudson job and then retrieve all the GAVP param. Is there a way to read hudson configuration in which i would have anyway specified the pom location ?

Comment: The WORKSPACE variable points to the workspace of your the executing job. If you build 1 per hudson job then you will only have 1 pom.xml.

Comment: Okay. Will give that a shot. Another question, Is there a way in which I can refer to the artifact built before the "Execute Shell" step ? Is yes, that would be very useful in terms of referring to the artifact to to be deployed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'the artifact built'. The name of the maven artifact (~project name) or rather the name of the generated jar file?

Comment: The URL to the nexus repository where the artifact is located.

Comment: Why do you need that, you can just pick the jar/war from the target folder in ${WORKSPACE}. Hudson is not aware of nexus since this is done on maven level, usually this is done in the settings.xml in which case even the pom.xml would not help you.